# how to make sphinx less verbose through sphinx.conf

Tags: php, sphinx

A third party implemented sphinx search into our php application (we use the pecl extension).

Sphinx writes a lot of deprecation warnings into our apache error.log (DEPRECATED: Do not call this method or, even better, use SphinxQL instead of an API).

How can we disable these deprecation warnings or lower the verbosity of errors being logged?

Comment: Try googling "php lower the verbosity of warnings"

Answer (score 0):

Set error_reporting() to not report `E_USER_DEPRECATED`  warnings.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php